# Unexpected in memory relationship values of NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

#### Demo

Why does this test succeed? https://github.com/Ckitakishi/CoreData-Conflict-Demo/blob/main/CoreDataConflictDemoTests/MergeConflictTests.swift#L12-L42

#### Description

There're 3 contexts **on same coordinator**, which means they share the row cache.

1. Insert the following data to DB on `context1`:

```swift
/// EntityA(attribute: 100).toManyRelationship = [EntityB(attribute: 10), EntityB(attribute: 11)]
/// EntityA(attribute: 200).toManyRelationship = [EntityB(attribute: 11), EntityB(attribute: 12)]
///
/// EntityB(attribute: 10).toManyRelationship = [EntityA(attribute: 100)]
/// EntityB(attribute: 11).toManyRelationship = [EntityA(attribute: 100), EntityA(attribute: 200)]
/// EntityB(attribute: 12).toManyRelationship = [EntityA(attribute: 200)]
```

2. Set `mergePolicy` of `context1` to **`.overwrite`**.
3. Delete `EntityB(attribute: 10)` from `EntityA(attribute: 100)` on `context1`, **do not save**.
4. Delete `EntityB(attribute: 11)` from `EntityA(attribute: 100)` on `context2`, save changes.
5. Save changes on `context1`, where a conflict will occur..
6. Conflict is solved by Core Data, currently the data stored in DB is like:

```swift
/// EntityA(attribute: 100).toManyRelationship = []
/// EntityA(attribute: 200).toManyRelationship = [EntityB(attribute: 11), EntityB(attribute: 12)]
///
/// EntityB(attribute: 10).toManyRelationship = []
/// EntityB(attribute: 11).toManyRelationship = [EntityA(attribute: 200)]
/// EntityB(attribute: 12).toManyRelationship = [EntityA(attribute: 200)]
```

6. However, if we fetch data on `context3` with a newly created fetch request, the data would be:

```swift
/// EntityA(attribute: 100).toManyRelationship = [EntityB(attribute: 10)] ??????
/// ...Remaning are same as above
```

#### Discussion/Question

1. I think the relationship data are fetched from row cache instead of SQLite store, but why `EntityA(attribute: 100).toManyRelationship` is not empty?
2. And, if inserting the data on a different context like `context4` or contexts on other coordinator, doing 2~6 will result in the same data as SQLite storage. (Which is what I think it should be.)

Do you have any idea about above questions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mention the merge policy, but are you performing merges anywhere? They don't happen automatically unless you use `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent`.

Comment: Thank you Tom, I didn't performing merges since `context3` is a newly created context after all changes have been saved.
I tried to set `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent` to `true`, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: That doesn’t work unless you have a parent/child relationship between contexts, that’s why “from parent” is in the name.